# Inline asm jmp - 'invalid operand for instruction'

Tags: assembly, rust, x86, inline-assembly

I'm doing some code injections, and I find it difficult to transcribe the code from C to Rust.

The situation is as follows, at the relative address 0x40147D we put a jump to the address of the instruction injected by the dll, this was done by inserting the bytes manually.

```
let rel = target_address - to_hook - 5;

let bytes: [u8; 4] =  transmute(rel.to_be());

buf[0] = 0xE9;

for x in 1..5 {
    buf[x] = bytes[4-x]
}
```

So we run any code in asm and at the end it should return to 0x401484 which is instruction 0x40147D + 7.
In C this works as expected, in Rust it doesn't.

C:

```
DWORD jmp_back = 0x40147D + 7;

__asm {
    add dword ptr[ebp - 0x0C], 03
    mov eax, [ebp - 0x0C]
    jmp [jmp_back]
}
```

Rust (I put a label to not crash the program):

```
let jump_back: u32 = 0x40147D + 7;

unsafe {
    asm!(
        "2:",
        "add dword ptr [ebp-0x0C],01",
        "mov eax,[ebp-0x0C]",
        // "jmp 2b", //back to label 2
        "jmp [{}]", in(reg) jump_back,

        // 'invalid operand for instruction' 
        //"jmp 0x401484" 

    );
 }
```

What is going unnoticed ?

**EDIT**

As commented by @prl, removing the square brackets resulted in:

[image]

I'm researching to know what is actually inside the eax register.
But with this modification the program crashes and closes.

**OBS**
To test, I removed the previous jmp instruction ("jmp 5D7B145D")

**EDIT 2**

As described [Inline Asm](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/inline-assembly.html), apparently to use values as operands in instructions, Rust loads the values into a register at the beginning of the block.

So maybe that's the problem that my instructions also use the same register.

I'll try later, but I'll probably have to change the register used by Rust.

[image]

The ideal is not having to use registers for such an action.

**EDIT 3**

So far I leave my answer as a solution to this question, but it still has problems.

Rust as the first instruction of the asm block moves the values you want to use into a register, a few points:

- If the register contains values in it ?
- Why not use constants in block asm ?

Comment: @prl I made the change, in the post edit I show the image, but with that the program now crashes and closes

Comment: I made a second edit to the post and indeed using operands in Rust results in loading them into registers. My question is, is it possible to get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a possible solution that only uses eax:

```
asm!(
    "push eax",
    "add dword ptr [ebp-0x0C],01",
    "mov eax,[ebp-0x0C]",
    "ret", in("eax") jump_back,
);
```

The `push` puts the location to jump to onto the stack, and the `ret` jumps to that location after loading eax, avoiding the need for a separate register to hold the address.

Comment: thanks, but that doesn't work in Rust "in(eax)". In fact out("eax") _ is the solution so that the injected assembly code does not use the register. Another point is that "ret" is meaningless in context. The execution of this code snippet was not by a calling instruction, but by a jmp.

Comment: And the "push eax" instruction can cause problems.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I was able to visualize it here, it worked. But it still raises a point, and if the eax register is being used ?, Rust adds the instruction " mov eax, "variable" " at the beginning of the scope. Causing previous information to be lost. There's no way to avoid it since it's the first instruction.

Comment: I thought the whole point of this code injection is to modify eax. If you intend to do something else, a different solution would be required.

Answer (score 3):

Use `jmp {}` instead of `jmp [{}]`. Rust puts the operand in a register instead of in memory like the C code does. `jmp [{}]` would  cause it to try to read the destination address from the memory location specified in the register.
The  C version needs brackets because the destination address hasn't been loaded into a register.

You also need to let the compiler know that inline assembly code uses eax, so the compiler doesn't use eax for the operand. To indicate that eax is clobbered, add another output operand  `out("eax") _`. The `_` indicates that the value can be discarded.

```
asm!(
    "add dword ptr [ebp-0x0C],01",
    "mov eax,[ebp-0x0C]",
    "jmp {}", in(reg) jump_back, out("eax") _
);
```

This has the drawback that it uses a register chosen by the compiler, which may already be in use at the location of the code injection.

If the compiler by default chooses a register that isn't available, but another register is available, the register to use can be specified. For example, `in("edx") jump_back` would tell the compiler to use edx.

Answer (score -1):

This may be a temporary solution, but as mentioned in the post, it may result in future issues.

As commented by [prl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8422330/prl), the snippet "out("eax") _ makes the generated asm not use this register.

```
unsafe {
    asm!(
        "add dword ptr [ebp-0x0C],01",
        "mov eax,[ebp-0x0C]",
        "jmp {}", in(reg) 0x401484u32,
        out("eax") _
     );
}
```

Generated assembly

[image]

Highlighted is what can cause future problems.